# How to validate that an input is a Date

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate that an input is a valid in this format : 2013/12/21

```
var val = $.trim($(this).val());
if (val != "") {
   if (val.search(/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/)==-1) {

   }
}
```

I have this code but it fail and I don't know why

Comment: Please try this regex: `^\d{4}-((0\d)|(1[012]))-(([012]\d)|3[01])$`.

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems." before you can solve a problem using regular expressions, you must first define what ***exactly*** you're trying to match. Does the format you've listed allow for 1-digit months and days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax error, double check your code !

```
var val = $.trim($(this).val());
if (val != "") {
   if (val.search(/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/)==-1) {
                                          Here ! you forgot your / 
   }
}
```